# body is not 100% height

Tags: html, css

```
<body>    
<div id='top'>this is top</div>
some text... 
</body>
```

css

```
html{
    height:100%;
    background:green;
}
body{
    max-width:50%;
    height:100%;  //doesn't work
    background:red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#top{
    height:30px;
    background:blue;
}
```

When `some text...` in the `body` tag is long enough that a scrollbar appears, `body` stops to be 100% height.

I need colored body to the bottom of page, regardless of amount of text in it.

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4pxng/2/)

Comment: What browser are you looking in? Did you try adding min-height: 100%;

Comment: It appears to be working as you intend in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without using any extra elements:

```
body{
    max-width:50%;
    min-height:100%; // this is for when text does not go down to bottom of page
    height: auto;    // this is for when text overflows the page
    background:red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here is a working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pxng/19/).

Answer (score 2):

You should used another `<div>` Tag.

```
<div id="content">asdomasdosamd oasdimsad </div>
```

and have this one colored too:

```
// css
#content { background: red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4pxng/16/

Comment: This is definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `height: 100%;`. The background color will stay red regardless of the amount of text then.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pxng/17/)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not the best solution, but here is a kind of fix :

Add `display:table;` to your body.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NcYCB/)**